# MySQL query to get the max, min with GROUP BY and multiple table joins in separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure

**employee_salary**

```
salary_id  |    emp_id    |   salary
```

**employee tabe structure**

```
emp_id | first_name | last_name | gender | email | mobile | dept_id | is_active
```

**Department:**

```
dept_id | dept_name | manager_name | is_active
```

**Question:**

Display department wise employee who is getting highest and lowest salary amount?

I am using query

```
SELECT   max(salary) salary,  dept_name, first_name, dept_id , 'MAX' Type
FROM    ( 
        SELECT     a.salary, c.dept_name, b.first_name, b.dept_id, a.salary_id
        FROM       employee_salary a
        LEFT JOIN  employee b 
        ON         a.emp_id = b.emp_id
        LEFT JOIN  department c 
        ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
        ) t
GROUP BY dept_id

UNION ALL

SELECT   min(salary) salary,  dept_name, first_name, dept_id , 'MIN' Type
FROM    ( 
        SELECT     a.salary, c.dept_name, b.first_name, b.dept_id, a.salary_id
        FROM       employee_salary a
        LEFT JOIN  employee b 
        ON         a.emp_id = b.emp_id
        LEFT JOIN  department c 
        ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
        ) t
GROUP BY dept_id

ORDER BY dept_id
```

The output I am getting is shown below . 
**I am not able to get the respective first name from employee table and rest all other fields are showing correct values,**

```
salary  dept_name   first_name  dept_id Type

30000   dept_1      Paul        1       MIN
98000   dept_1      Paul        1       MAX
51000   dept_2      Aron        2       MAX
20000   dept_2      Aron        2       MIN
40000   dept_3      Steve       3       MAX
40000   dept_3      Steve       3       MIN
64000   dept_4      Henry       4       MAX
64000   dept_4      Henry       4       MIN
```

Comment: Is Department 3 and Department 4's data valid? is the mix/max the same person due to the department being small? And does each query by itself produce the results you are seeking?

Comment: Thd first_name is showing the redundant data.. selecting any one from the department. The department s and dept 4 has only one - one entry and showing fine output

Comment: Do you know if it is the "min" query, or the "max" query that is producing for you the incorrect result? Does Paul from department 1 make 30,000 or 98,000?

Comment: You are misusing `GROUP BY`. MySQL has a pernicious extension to standard `GROUP BY` that lets you do this. Please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER the salary with DESC for finding the maximum value and by ASC for finding the MINIMUM salary
This is because it checked the first matched term, and return the value accordingly,

```
   SELECT max(salary) salary,  dept_name, first_name, dept_id , 'MAX' Type
    FROM ( SELECT a.salary, c.dept_name, b.first_name, b.dept_id, a.salary_id
    FROM employee_salary a
    LEFT JOIN employee b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
    LEFT JOIN department c ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id ORDER BY a.salary DESC) t
    group by dept_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT min(salary) salary,  dept_name, first_name, dept_id , 'MIN' Type
    FROM ( SELECT a.salary, c.dept_name, b.first_name, b.dept_id, a.salary_id
    FROM employee_salary a
    LEFT JOIN employee b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
    LEFT JOIN department c ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id  ORDER BY a.salary ASC) t
    group by dept_id
    ORDER BY dept_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have in your select list a value that is not an aggregate function or included in your group by.   Select the name after you have determined that the employeeid has the highest or lowest salary.

Comment: Well, you can - but I like the way you're thinking

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you're trying to obtain both an aggregate (`GROUP BY`) result and a detail result (the employee name) in just one query. You can't do that the way you're trying to do.

Let's break it down. You need to find the minimum salary for each department. That you do like this:

```
     SELECT  MIN(a.salary) salary, b.dept_id
       FROM  employee_salary a
  LEFT JOIN  employee b   ON  a.emp_id = b.emp_id
  LEFT JOIN  department c ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
   GROUP BY  b.dept_id
```

That gives you a list of minimum salaries.  Next, you have to find which employee has that minimum salary in each department:  So, you have to JOIN this query to another one. That looks like this:

```
     SELECT a.salary, c.dept_name, b.first_name, b.dept_id
       FROM employee_salary a
  LEFT JOIN employee b ON  a.emp_id = b.emp_id
  LEFT JOIN department c ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
       JOIN ( /* the above aggregate query */
               SELECT  MIN(a.salary) salary, b.dept_id
                 FROM  employee_salary a
            LEFT JOIN  employee b   ON  a.emp_id = b.emp_id
            LEFT JOIN  department c ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
             GROUP BY  b.dept_id
            ) d ON d.salary=a.salary AND d.dept_id = b.dept_id
```

This will give you the employee / department / salary detail data corresponding to the employee (or employees) having the minimum salary in each department.

You can do the same thing to get the employees with maximum salaries.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but it seems to work. Made a derived table of minumum and maximum salaries and joined it to the rest of the tables.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f455e1/4)**

```
select es.salary,
  ds.dept_name,
  e.first_name,
  ds.dept_id,
  'MAX' Type
from employee_salary es
join employee e on es.emp_id = e.emp_id
join
  (SELECT     b.dept_id,
              c.dept_name, 
             max(salary) as 'MaxSalary' 
   FROM       employee_salary a
   LEFT JOIN  employee b 
     ON         a.emp_id = b.emp_id
   LEFT JOIN  department c 
     ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
   GROUP BY b.dept_id, c.dept_name) ds on e.dept_id = ds.dept_id and es.salary = ds.maxsalary

UNION ALL

select es.salary,
  ds.dept_name,
  e.first_name,
  ds.dept_id,
  'MIN' Type
from employee_salary es
join employee e on es.emp_id = e.emp_id
join
  (SELECT     b.dept_id,
              c.dept_name, 
           min(salary) as 'MinSalary'
   FROM       employee_salary a
   LEFT JOIN  employee b 
    ON         a.emp_id = b.emp_id
   LEFT JOIN  department c 
    ON c.dept_id = b.dept_id
   GROUP BY b.dept_id, c.dept_name) ds on e.dept_id = ds.dept_id and es.salary = ds.minsalary

ORDER BY dept_id, salary
```